# How to add header or request param to getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I want to pass a simple string value or a JWT access token to the `getServerSideProps` function in NextJS, then I want to do some requests for the user from the server side.
My JWT access token is currently stored in memory (in a state).

**How do I pass my JWT access token or any other string value to `getServerSideProps`?**

I have read many times that you can pass cookies to `getServerSideProps` but I wanted to add this access token value to the request header or request param.

Is there any other way than cookies or querystring parameter to add custom values to the `getServerSideProps` function in nextjs that is executed on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to `getServerSideProps` if you set up a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). You can use their example to parse the url and then add values to the query, but note that their example uses `URL.parse` from node and that has been deprecated so you'll want to modify it for more recent versions of node.

A second way to handle this (still using a custom server) would be to take advantage of [Express-style response locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals). Using their first example on the above-linked Next page, it could look like this:

```js
// Custom Server
...
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    res.locals.myServerValue = "someValue"
    handle(req, res)
  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
...
```

Now in `getServerSideProps`, you can access this value from the response object:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  // Get the value from res.locals
  const myServerValue = res.locals.myServerValue

  // Do something with myServerValue
  console.log(myServerValue) // prints "someValue"

  // If desired, pass the value to the page if that's how you're using it
  return {
    props: {
      myServerValue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What value does creating a custom server bring in this case? The same could be achieve with `getServerSideProps` alone. From reading OP's question, I assumed the value to pass would be different per request.

Comment: The value of the custom server is that you can pass values to `getServerSideProps`. The user was asking how to pass values into `getServerSideProps` without using cookies (things like request headers or additional values). In this case, some processing or setup would have to run before `getServerSideProps` which means it would need to happen on a custom server before Next is handled, and then passed into Next which can then be handled in `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Yes, but you could very well run that processing/setup inside `getServerSideProps` directly, without using a custom server.

Comment: Yes - I think we're interpreting OP's question differently. OP is asking specifically how to pass things TO `getServerSideProps`, which I'm reading as, "I am doing some stuff like JWT verification before Next loads up, and I want to pass some result of that to `getServerSideProps` so I can do some more stuff in Next before my page renders." While you can do that JWT verification in `getServerSideProps`, OP is asking how to do it outside of `getServerSideProps` and then pass some data IN to `getServerSideProps`. And for that, you'd need a custom server.

Comment: Got it, fair enough

Comment: Hey, yes I wanted to add some state value from client side to `getServerSideProps`. I dont know if a custom server helps me in this case. I wanted to know if I can pass a value that is created and stored in the client side app from redux store state or react context to `getServerSideProps` without using cookies or queryStrings. I thought there was something like an interceptor for adding request parameter to the `getServerSideProps` request in specific situations (example: If a specific state value is filled then pass it to further `getServerSideProps` calls).